# Set a path depending on the active route using angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following in my `app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '../../node_modules/@angular/router';
import { LoginService } from '../../src/app/service/login.service';
import { ImageService } from '../../src/app/service/image.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Logikal.pro';
  error;

  @ViewChild("bgPhoto") photo:ElementRef;

  constructor(private router:Router, 
              private loginService:LoginService,
              private imageService:ImageService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.loginService.logOut();
    this.router.navigate(['']) // going home on refresh browser

    this.getPhoto('laptop.jpg');
  }


  getPhoto(res:string){
    return this.imageService.loadImage(res).subscribe(
      image => {
        this.photo.nativeElement.style = 'background:url('+URL.createObjectURL(image)+') center center no-repeat;background-size:cover;';


      },
      error =>{
        console.error(error);
        this.error = error;
      }
    )

  }

}
```

This piece of code works pretty well, but I would like to improve my `getPhoto` function. This function only takes a photo from a server and shows it on the screen as a background image. Every child component is using this image as a background.

What I would like to do is retrieving the route of the current active child component in order to show a specific image in the background, using a `switch` in my function. Of course I will have to use something else than `ngOnInit` event function to place my code, but which event?

Is it possible this way? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved my problem. But I would like to get your opinion on it, or discover other solutions.

```
ngOnInit(){
    let snapshot;
    this.loginService.logOut();
    this.router.navigate(['']); // going home on refresh browser
    this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
  ).subscribe(() => {
      snapshot = this.activatedRoute.root.snapshot;
      console.log(snapshot._routerState.url);
      switch(snapshot._routerState.url){
        case '/':
        this.getPhoto('laptop.jpg');
        break;
        case '/about':
        this.getPhoto('code.jpg');
        break;
        case '/news':
        this.getPhoto('startup-desktop.jpg')
        break;
        case '/cv':
        this.getPhoto('tablet.jpg')
        break;
        case '/dl':
        this.getPhoto('tablet.jpg')
        break;
        case '/contact':
        this.getPhoto('tablet.jpg')
        break;
        case 'default':
        this.getPhoto('tablet.jpg')
        break;
      }
  });
```